# TSQL - Islands and gaps for contiguous schedules without overlaps

Tags: sql, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

Once again I'm running into an islands and gaps problem regarding schedule output, and some help would be greatly appreciated.

In my example, I have list of user schedules containing of schedule containers (intType = 1) and schedule parts (intType = 0) and I've been asked to figure out how to pass a contiguous schedule instead of the overlapping style I've been using in this system for years.  Currently *MOST* schedule parts fall inside the start and end time of a Schedule container, with the exception of one code (intCode=32), which already has a start time and end time at the beginning and end of any two schedule containers, as seen in the example below.

```
DECLARE @Schedule TABLE (
intUserID BIGINT,
dtDate DATETIME,
dtStart DATETIME,
dtStop DATETIME,
intCode INT,
intType INT);

INSERT INTO @Schedule
   ([dtDate]
   ,[intUserID]
   ,[dtStart]
   ,[dtStop]
   ,[intCode]
   ,[intType])
select '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 10:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 19:00:00.000',  46, 1
union 
select '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 12:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 12:15:00.000',  66, 0
union 
select '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 12:20:00.000',  '2017-02-23 12:26:00.000',  110,0
union
SELECT '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 14:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 15:00:00.000',  76, 0
union 
SELECT '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 17:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 17:15:00.000',  66, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 10:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 19:00:00.000',  46, 1
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 12:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 12:15:00.000',  66, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 14:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 15:00:00.000',  76, 0
union
select '2017-02-22 00:00:00',   888888888888,   '2017-02-22 17:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 17:15:00.000',  66, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 19:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 21:00:00.000',  32, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 21:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 21:30:00.000',  46, 1
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 21:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 21:30:00.000',  59, 0


SELECT * FROM @Schedule ORDER BY intUserID, dtDate, dtStart, intType DESC
```

This gives us the current schedule storage data which looks like this:

```
intUserID    dtDate           dtStart          dtStop           intCode intType
------------ ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ------- -------
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 10:00 2017-02-23 19:00      46       1
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 12:00 2017-02-23 12:15      66       0
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 12:20 2017-02-23 12:26     110       0
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 14:00 2017-02-23 15:00      76       0
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 17:00 2017-02-23 17:15      66       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 10:00 2017-02-22 19:00      46       1
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 12:00 2017-02-22 12:15      66       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 14:00 2017-02-22 15:00      76       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 17:00 2017-02-22 17:15      66       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 19:00 2017-02-22 21:00      32       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 21:00 2017-02-22 21:30      46       1
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 21:00 2017-02-22 21:30      59       0
```

The new request is to have a schedule container fill all time between the original start and end time of the schedule where there is no schedule part, or something that looks like this:

```
intUserID    dtDate           dtStart          dtStop           intCode intType
------------ ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ------- -------
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 10:00 2017-02-23 12:00      46       1
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 12:00 2017-02-23 12:15      66       0
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 12:15 2017-02-23 12:20      46       1
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 12:20 2017-02-23 12:26     110       0
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 12:26 2017-02-23 14:00      46       1
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 14:00 2017-02-23 15:00      76       0
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 15:00 2017-02-23 17:00      46       1
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 17:00 2017-02-23 17:15      66       0
444444444444 2017-02-23 00:00 2017-02-23 17:15 2017-02-23 19:00      46       1
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 10:00 2017-02-22 12:00      46       1
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 12:00 2017-02-22 12:15      66       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 12:15 2017-02-22 14:00      46       1
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 14:00 2017-02-22 15:00      76       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 15:00 2017-02-22 17:00      46       1
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 17:00 2017-02-22 17:15      66       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 17:15 2017-02-22 19:00      46       1
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 19:00 2017-02-22 21:00      32       0
888888888888 2017-02-22 00:00 2017-02-22 21:00 2017-02-22 21:30      59       0
```

As you can see the difference is that the schedule container in the second scenario becomes the "Water" to fill in the time between schedule parts, with a boundary equal to the original start and end times of the container.

I Hope that I was able to explain adequately, or if not, the expected outputs will help someone formulate something that can assist me in this endeavor without looping through all the schedules as there are literally thousands of them to output and speed is necessary.

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided!

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the answer would lie within setting the boundaries of the schedules and filling in the gaps, and it appears I was right.  If anyone is interested in double checking my work, the solution I used is as follows:

```
DECLARE @Schedule TABLE (
intUserID BIGINT,
dtDate DATETIME,
dtStart DATETIME,
dtEnd DATETIME,
intCode INT,
intType INT);

INSERT INTO @Schedule
   ([dtDate]
   ,[intUserID]
   ,[dtStart]
   ,[dtEnd]
   ,[intCode]
   ,[intType])
select '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 10:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 19:00:00.000',  46, 1
union 
select '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 12:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 12:15:00.000',  66, 0
union 
select '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 12:20:00.000',  '2017-02-23 12:26:00.000',  110,0
union
SELECT '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 14:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 15:00:00.000',  76, 0
union 
SELECT '2017-02-23 00:00:00',   444444444444,   '2017-02-23 17:00:00.000',  '2017-02-23 17:15:00.000',  66, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 10:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 19:00:00.000',  46, 1
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 12:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 12:15:00.000',  66, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 14:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 15:00:00.000',  76, 0
union
select '2017-02-22 00:00:00',   888888888888,   '2017-02-22 17:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 17:15:00.000',  66, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 19:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 21:00:00.000',  32, 0
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 21:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 21:30:00.000',  46, 1
union
select  '2017-02-22 00:00:00',  888888888888,   '2017-02-22 21:00:00.000',  '2017-02-22 21:30:00.000',  59, 0




DECLARE @tmpSchedule TABLE (
dtDate datetime
,dtStart datetime
,dtEnd datetime
,intCode int
,intType int
,intUserID bigint
)

DECLARE @tmpBaseCodes TABLE (
dtDate datetime
,intCode int
,intUserID bigint null
)

insert into @tmpSchedule
-- Create schedule boundaries
select dtDate, dtStart, dtStart dtEnd, intCode, intType, intUserID from @Schedule where inttype = 1
union
select dtDate, dtEnd dtStart, dtEnd, intCode, intType, intUserID from @Schedule where intType = 1
union
select dtDate, dtStart, dtEnd, intCode, intType, intUserID from @Schedule where inttype = 0

insert into @tmpBaseCodes
select dtDate, min(intCode) intCode, intUserID from @tmpSchedule where intType = 1 group by dtDate, intUserID;
-- Calculate gaps and apply base code between them
WITH C1 AS (
        SELECT dtDate, intUserID, ts, Type
            ,e=CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dtDate,intUserID, Type ORDER BY dtEnd) END
            ,s=CASE Type WHEN -1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dtDate,intUserID, Type ORDER BY dtStart) END
        FROM @tmpSchedule
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (1, dtStart), (-1, dtEnd)) a(Type, ts)
        ),
    C2 AS (
        SELECT C1.*
            ,se=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dtDate,intUserID ORDER BY ts, Type DESC)
        FROM C1),
    C3 AS (
        SELECT dtDate,intUserID, ts
            ,grpnm=FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dtDate, intUserID ORDER BY ts)-1) / 2 + 1)
        FROM C2
        WHERE COALESCE(s-(se-s)-1, (se-e)-e) = 0),
    -- C1, C2, C3, C4 combined remove the overlapping date periods
    C4 AS (
        SELECT dtDate, intUserID, dtStart=MIN(ts), dtEnd=MAX(ts)
        FROM C3
        GROUP BY dtDate, intUserID, grpnm)
INSERT INTO @tmpSchedule
(dtdate, dtstart, dtend, intCode, intType, intUserID)
SELECT a.dtDate, dtStart=MIN(newdate), dtEnd=MAX(newdate), b.intCode, 1 intType, a.intUserID
FROM (
    SELECT dtDate, newdate, intUserID
        ,rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dtDate,intUserID ORDER BY newdate) / 2
    FROM C4 a
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (dtStart),(dtEnd)) b(newdate)
    ) a
JOIN @tmpBaseCodes b on b.dtDate = a.dtDate and b.intUserID = a.intUserID
GROUP BY a.dtDate, a.intUserID, b.intCode, rn
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY intUserID, dtDate, dtStart;

-- Select the entries from the schedule except boundaries
select * from @tmpSchedule
where dtStart != dtEnd
order by intUserID,dtDate, dtStart, intType desc
```